# meaning of $@ in unix shell script

Tags: unix

this is my piece of code:

```
##Checking swapspace if ignore option chosen will force creation of swap space
echo ; echo "[INFO]: Validating Swap space "
swapspace=`swapon -s|tail -1|awk '{print $3/1024}'`
if [ ${swapspace} -le 500 ]; then
        echo $@ |grep ignore>/dev/null
         if [ `echo $?` -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "[WARNING]: Swap space is below minimum requirement get the same fixed :${swapspace}
            Proceeding with WorkAround. PLEASE GET IT FIXED AT THE EARLIEST"

                dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=2G  count=4
                chmod 0600 /swapfile; mkswap /swapfile; swapon /swapfile
                export SWAPFLAG=1

        else
         echo "[ERROR]: Swap space is below minimum requirement get the same fixed :${swapspace}"
          export SWAPFLAG=2
        fi


fi
```

can someone please explain what is echo $@ doing here?

PS: 'ignore is a hidden argument'

Comment: Surbhi: Kindly do not mention capital letters in your post/question. You should provide complete details of your question and then expected output too for a better guidance on your question, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Surbhi:
`$@` denotes all of the parameters passed to the script. eg--> `./test.ksh test1 test2` then `$@` will be equal to `test1 test2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a shell script with arguments e.g:

```
./myscript goodbye cruel world
```

you can access those arguments within the script. In particular `$@` gives you them all as they were typed - e.g. if `myscript.sh` is

```
#! /bin/sh
echo $@
```

the above command simply prints `goodbye cruel world` to the terminal